# media scanner running

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gridview, android-mediascanner

in my application user captures the images through camera functionality after that i am going to update the image in grid view .but those are not updated after long search i found need to run media scanner manually .i write code for that .but when i capturing images repeatedly   it gives error.below i posted my log cat errors....

```
11-05 17:17:17.565: E/AndroidRuntime(30801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 17:17:17.565: E/AndroidRuntime(30801): java.lang.IllegalStateException: not connected to MediaScannerService
11-05 17:17:17.565: E/AndroidRuntime(30801):    at android.media.MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MediaScannerConnection.java:164)
11-05 17:17:17.565: E/AndroidRuntime(30801):    at com.imagedatabase.Category$6.onMediaScannerConnected(Category.java:512)
11-05 17:17:17.565: E/AndroidRuntime(30801):    at android.media.MediaScannerConnection.onServiceConnected(MediaScannerConnection.java:249)
11-05 17:17:17.565: E/AndroidRuntime(30801):    at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(ActivityThread.java:1247)
11-05 17:17:17.565: E/AndroidRuntime(30801):    at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(ActivityThread.java:1264)
11-05 17:17:17.565: E/AndroidRuntime(30801):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-05 17:17:17.565: E/AndroidRuntime(30801):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-05 17:17:17.565: E/AndroidRuntime(30801):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-05 17:17:17.565: E/AndroidRuntime(30801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
```

below i posted the my code where i am going to run this one and i am explaining each and every step in comments.

```
    enter code here

   public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View view) {

        //when camera button is pressed it starts 
            startCameraActivity();


    }
}




public void startCameraActivity() {

       //seperating the images with date




    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-kk-mm-ss");
    String newPicFile = df.format(date);



    direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + path
            + "/" + newPicFile + ".jpg");



    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(direct);

                           //here i am starting the  camra 



    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);




   }




enter code here

      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i("image data base", "resultCode: " + resultCode);
    switch (resultCode) {
    case 0:
                        //when user cancel the image take here i am deleted the urifile


        File file = new File(outputFileUri.getPath());
        boolean deleted = file.delete();

        Log.i("image data based", "User cancelled");
        break;

    case -1:
        onPhotoTaken();

        break;
    }
     }
```

//in this on photo taken i wrote the code for media scanner

```
enter code here
protected void onPhotoTaken() {

    Log.i("MakeMachine", "onPhotoTaken");

    taken = true;
    SharedPreferences path_shared = Category.this.getSharedPreferences(
            "path", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    imagePath = path_shared.getString("mypath", "0");

    File newFile = new File(imagePath);
    final Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newFile);

    mScanner = new MediaScannerConnection(Category.this,
            new MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
                public void onMediaScannerConnected() {

        mScanner.scanFile(outputFileUri.getPath(), null /* mimeType */);
                }

                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

            if (path.equals(outputFileUri.getPath())) {
            mScanner.disconnect();
        // we need to create new UI thread because, we can't
    // update our mail thread from here
        // Both the thread will run one by one, see
                        // documentation of android
            Category.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
    mScanner.connect();
               }
```

i hope u got my point i also tried with

```
     sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,Uri.parse("file://" + \
      outputFileUri+  Environment. getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

but it some what slow i think it scan the entire sd card .so can any one please guide me how to run media scanner and also where can i run in my code.i searched lot but those are not satisfy my needs .